# How to delete root element of XML file via PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have an XML document & a PHP file.

I want to delete the root element of the XML document under an if statement in the PHP file, meaning the XML file will be empty.

Is there a fast way to do this through DOM Document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the root element in a DOMDocument, you remove the document element (the root element as I read your question) from the document similar on how to remove any other child element:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<root/>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$doc->save('php://output');

echo "---\n";

$doc->removeChild($doc->documentElement);
$doc->save('php://output');
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root/>
---
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

(Running example: https://3v4l.org/u11Oo)

As this example shows, the document element has been removed from the document. If there would not be the XML declaration, it would be just empty.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming the XML document is a flat file on your server, you can forego having to do it with the DOM, and simply truncate the file contents like so:

```
$f = fopen("document.xml", "r+");
ftruncate($f, 0);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: This didn't work. I am getting an error of undefined variables. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code you used and the exact error message in your original post?